# How to make Username as non mandatory on Drupal 7 registration form?

Tags: users

I am working on a project where i want to remove the Username form registration from. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, there are couple of modules out there that will auto-generate the username and just require an email address on the registration form (and there are probably a few more as well)

- [Email registration](http://drupal.org/project/email_registration)

  > Allow users to register and login using only an email address. Users can then log-in using their email address and password for authentication.
  >
  > A username is generated and assigned based on the user name part of the email address. Subsequent users who have the same name (email prefix) are numbered sequentially. For example, "johndoe@a.example.com" would be assigned username "johndoe", "johndoe@b.example.com" would be assigned "johndoe_1" and so forth. Sites that want to create usernames in their own way can do so by implementing hook_email_registration_name.
- [Login Toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)

  > The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal login system in an external module by offering the following features and usability improvements:
  >
  > 1. Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail address.

Out of those two Email Registration is a bit more lightweight, so if you don't need the features from LoginToboggan it would make more sense to use that one.

Comment: Hey Clive, I had installed email registration module not able to configure it can up please help me out with this...?